# How can I get Chrome multiple users to recognize symlinked extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, symbolic-link, multiple-users

I have multiple Chrome users.

To save time and space on extensions that are the same (state / prefs / etc) across all users, I've symlinked most extensions (e.g. `Profile 4/Extensions/xyz` -> `Default/Extensions/xyz`).

Unfortunately, they don't seem to be recognized by Chrome (e.g. logging in as user 4, it shows no extensions installed).

How can I get Chrome to obey those symlinks?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, extensions can't simply be copied from Profile to Profile.  They must be deployed to new Profiles.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry

> An extension that's installed automatically is known as an external
>   extension. Google Chrome supports two ways of installing external
>   extensions:
>
> Using a preferences JSON file Using the Windows registry (Windows
>   only)